# How can I import a local file into an Azure Function using Node?

Tags: node.js, import, azure-functions

I am writing an Azure Function in Node with some reusable code. I'd simply like to import it using:

```
import { myUtilsFunc } from '../utils';
```

This seems to work locally but I sometimes get an error saying `utils` cannot be found.

Is there something I am missing? Perhaps a property in the Azure Function JSON file?

Comment: Can you please share your full code?

Answer (score 1):

The file should be available in the deployed files in Azure Function to import.

`import` statements are part of ECMAScript modules [ESM](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html), which is a standard for organizing and structuring JavaScript code. It started to support ECMAScript modules with the introduction of the `.mjs` file extension and the `"type": "module"` field in `package.json`

You need to add file name in the code:

```js
import {myUtilsFunc} from  '../utils/myUtilsFunc.mjs';
```

**#This is my directory:**

```
My function
├── HttpTrigger1
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── function.json
├── utils
│   ├── myUtilsFunc.mjs
├── host.json
├── local.settings.json
├── ... //other files
└── package.json
```

**`index.js`:**

```js
import {myUtilsFunc} from '../utils/myUtilsFunc.mjs';

export default async function (context, req) {
    context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');

    const responseMessage = myUtilsFunc();
    context.res = {
        // status: 200, /* Defaults to 200 */
        body: responseMessage
    };
}
```

**`function.json`:**

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    }
  ]
}
```

**`myUtilsFunc.mjs`:**

```js
const myUtilsFunc = () => {
    return 'Hello from myUtilsFunc!';
  };
  
  export { myUtilsFunc };
```

**`package.json`:**

```json
{
  "name": "nodejs",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\""
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

**`host.json`:**

```json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[4.*, 5.0.0)"
  }
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

**local:**

[image]

[image]

**Azure:**
[image]

[image]

[image]